# c# textbox вставка дефис через цифр

Tags: c#, winforms

есть textbox куда вводится номер телефона в таком формате 7-77-77, при вводе номера автоматом после первого символа вставлялся дефис. помогите пожалуйста советами как это реализовать, в интернете нашел вот такой код, вроде работает, но криво. выполняется после ввода, я бы хотел во время ввода сделать это

```
private void phonetextbox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
         string str = phonetextbox.Text;
        System.Text.StringBuilder result = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            result.Append(i % 2 == 1 && i > 0 ? $"-{str[i]}" : $"{str[i]}");
        phonetextbox.Text = ($"{result}");
        Activated -= phonetextbox_Leave;
    }
```

Comment: В WinForms есть MaskedTextBox, там паттерн задать сразу можно

Comment: да....  настолько грустно ?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: спасибо помогли, не могли бы подсказать насчет проверки вводимых данных с базой данных ? при ввода Textbox  сверялся с базой данных на наличие совпадение

Comment: @Misterjunior запрос на `WHERE`, если количество элементов == 1, то кидайте исключение. Ну или в самой БД можно проверять, добавить триггер на добавление

Comment: это на текст бокс повесить , textbox.Changed?

Comment: А вы попробуйте, не бойтесь